# ToggleClass won't work

Tags: jquery, css, toggleclass

I have some HTML that I want to "highlight" when I click on it. Pretty straightforward stuff, but i cannot for the life of me get toggleClass to work :/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    <div id="pageTop">
        ...
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <h2>2 Special Offers</h2>
        <p>1) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</p>
      <div id="prod1">
            <img src="images/prod1-1.png" width="130" height="109" alt="">
        </div>

        <div id="prod2">
            <div id="holdingBox1" class="one">
                <p>Choose from over 32 products</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="prod3">
            <div id="holdingBox2" class="two">
                <p>Choose from over 32 products</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flyout1">
        <div id="subProd">Prod 1</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 2</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 3</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 4</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 5</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 6</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 7</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 8</div>
    </div>

    <div class="flyout2">
        <div id="subProd">Prod 1</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 2</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 3</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 4</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 5</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 6</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 7</div>
        <div id="subProd">Prod 8</div>
    </div>

    <div id="restOfPage">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.flyout1').hide();
$("#holdingBox1").on("click",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    $(".flyout1").slideToggle();
    $(".flyout2").hide();
});
$('.flyout2').hide();
$("#holdingBox2").on("click",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    $(".flyout2").slideToggle();
    $(".flyout1").hide();
}); });
```

The slideToggle stuff on my hidden layers works great, adding other functions just seems to break it :/

Here is the CSS "hover" I am trying to apply

```
.hover { border:1px solid red; }
```

Any ideas on how i have monumentally c*cked this up would be greatly appreciated, as I just can't see what I am doing wrong :/

Comment: it's working for me http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/2U3Ww/2/

Comment: Note that you're hiding `.flyout2` on the click of `#holdingBox1`, but you're not removing the hover class of `#holdingBox2` at the same click, so the two can get out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tided up your `jquery` a little bit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2U3Ww/5/)

But it looks like your code is working. Unless there is something that you have not mentioned

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#holdingBox1").on("click",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    $(".flyout1").slideToggle();
    $(".flyout2").hide();
});

$("#holdingBox2").on("click",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    $(".flyout2").slideToggle();
    $(".flyout1").hide();
}); });
```

CSS

```
.hover { border:1px solid red; }
.flyout1{display:none;}
.flyout2{display:none;}
```

Comment: I run it in Chrome, Firefox and IE and it doesn't work, looks like I might have a conflicting CSS somewhere :/

I can't access JSFiddle from behind my companies firewall, well i can i just can't see the output window

Comment: you will need to give us more of the code for us to see what is not working

Comment: Looks like this some conflicting CSS. I have had to add !important to the .hover class. Cheers guys, least I know I was on the right track, now to code up the bit to eliminate the other conflicts...